# operation is not valid due to the current state of the object in C#

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle10g, odp.net

I have a trouble with my coding. This is a source code what I coding for this program.

```
    OracleConnection kon;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FillCombo();
    }

    void FillCombo()
    {
        OracleConnection kon = Koneksi.getKoneksi();
        OracleCommand cmd;
        try
        {
            kon.Open();
            cmd = new OracleCommand();
            cmd.Connection = kon;

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM JOBS";

            OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            comboBox1.Items.Add(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("JOB_ID")));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Data has been failed to show: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            kon.Close();
            kon.Dispose();
        }
    }
 }
```

}

When I running this program, system will show dialog "operation is not valid due to the current state of the object".

[When I running the Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkgEg.png)

[There's No Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqACD.png)

How to solve this error? I'll bind data to comboBox from database. I mean, I want to **add** JOB_ID to combo Box such as AD_VP, HR_REP, etc btw.

Btw, I'm sorry if my English is poor.

Comment: Which line is producing the error kon.Open? or, cmd.ExecuteReader?

Comment: Please show COMPLETE stack trace, and offending line of code.

Comment: Is it Windows or web application?

Comment: @BugFinder I don't know where's the line produced the error. Nothing list error in error list

Comment: There's nothing error, I don't know how to show the error. It just show dialog "operation is not valid due to the current state of the object" @OldProgrammer

Comment: Windows brother @OrkunBekar

Comment: If you run the app in debug, it should stop on the line and tell you which one is erroring

Comment: To get the full stack trace, change `ex.Message` to `ex.ToString()`

Comment: There's no error @BugFinder

Comment: Still no error when I try to changed that code @sstan

Comment: @Kgs.AzzamNizar but there is you tell us it says "operation is not valid due to the current state of the object" .. thats an error

Comment: but in box error list, there was no error. Check at my picture @BugFinder

Comment: @OP: The error list box will give you ***compilation*** errors.  The error you are getting is a ***runtime*** error. 2 very different kinds of errors.

Comment: How to see the runtime error? @sstan

Comment: @Kgs.AzzamNizar as we said, if it runs in debug mode, and you havent specifically gone out of your way to turn off runtime errors, you would have seen where the error was.

Comment: By catching the exception thrown during execution of the program, like your sample code does already, and then logging or displaying the exception details. You were already doing this by displaying the exception message in the message box. The only problem is that the exception message doesn't have all the useful details. That's why, when displaying an exception, you should use `ex.ToString()` instead of `ex.Message` to get the message + stack trace.  But as BugFinder points out, learning to use debug mode is even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One obvious thing that's missing is that you didn't call `reader.Read()` before attempting to read from your data reader.  When you call `OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();`, at that moment, the data reader is positioned ***before*** the first record.  You need to call `reader.Read()` to move it to the first record. This can easily explain the error you got.

```
OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read(); // Add this. Check for a return value of false if necessary.
comboBox1.Items.Add(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("JOB_ID")));
```

Apart from that, it would also be a good idea to dispose of the data reader properly. You may want to use a `using` block for this.

Comment: just AD_PRES in the combo Box

Answer (score -2):

So what youa re trying to do is Adding the ordial number of the JOB_ID column to a combobox. As you probably know GetOrdinal returns in int.
Why don't you just go like this:

```
...   
comboBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(reader.GetOrdinal("JOB_ID")));
...
```

Comment: OP's code is reading the ***value*** of `job_id`. Your suggested code returns the ***resultset index*** of `job_id`. Not the same thing.  But in any case, this is probably unrelated to OP's actual error.

Comment: I was trying your code, but just "0" in the comboBox. I mean, I want to add JOB_ID in comboBox such as AD_VP, HR_REP, etc.